# error message - deploying python project on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, mysql

I am facing problem while deploying python project in pythonanywhere. The error.log file is as follows. I would be very happy if you could help.

```
2021-06-04 14:32:41,881: Error running WSGI application
2021-06-04 14:32:41,881: mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'remotemysql.com:3306' (111 Connection refused)
2021-06-04 14:32:41,882:   File "/var/www/projecelikkiristasarim_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 79, in <module>
2021-06-04 14:32:41,882:     from main import app as application  # noqa
2021-06-04 14:32:41,882: 
2021-06-04 14:32:41,882:   File "/home/projecelikkiristasarim/ProjeCelikKirisTasarim/main.py", line 7, in <module>
2021-06-04 14:32:41,882:     mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
2021-06-04 14:32:41,882: 
2021-06-04 14:32:41,883:   File "/home/projecelikkiristasarim/.virtualenvs/gelistirmeortami/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
2021-06-04 14:32:41,883:     return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
2021-06-04 14:32:41,883: 
2021-06-04 14:32:41,883:   File "/home/projecelikkiristasarim/.virtualenvs/gelistirmeortami/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
2021-06-04 14:32:41,883:     self.connect(**kwargs)
2021-06-04 14:32:41,883: 
2021-06-04 14:32:41,883:   File "/home/projecelikkiristasarim/.virtualenvs/gelistirmeortami/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
2021-06-04 14:32:41,883:     self._open_connection()
2021-06-04 14:32:41,883: 
2021-06-04 14:32:41,883:   File "/home/projecelikkiristasarim/.virtualenvs/gelistirmeortami/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 206, in _open_connection
2021-06-04 14:32:41,883:     self._socket.open_connection()
2021-06-04 14:32:41,883: 
2021-06-04 14:32:41,884:   File "/home/projecelikkiristasarim/.virtualenvs/gelistirmeortami/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 511, in open_connection
2021-06-04 14:32:41,884:     raise errors.InterfaceError(
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using a free account on PythonAnywhere.  Free accounts have restricted Internet access, and can only connect to external systems using HTTP or HTTPS (not, for example, using the MySQL protocol) and are also limited to accessing sites on a [whitelist](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/).